# How would you solve $yy'+x = \dfrac{(x^2+y^2)^2}{2x^2}+\dfrac{x^2+y^2}{x}, \ x>0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

As the title suggests, we have
\begin{align}
yy'+x = \dfrac{(x^2+y^2)^2}{2x^2}+\dfrac{x^2+y^2}{x}, \ x>0.
\end{align}

I can guess that it is a homogeneous ODE, so I tried setting $z(x)=\dfrac{y(x)}{x}$ but the calculations are painstaking.

Any other ideas would be welcome.

Comment: $yy'$ is almost the derivative of $y^2$. Maybe you can solve it with $z(x)=y^2$.

Comment: With $x^2+y^2$ so prominently represented, it would make sense to extend this to $z(x)=x^2+y(x)^2$, as also $z'=2(yy'+x)=\frac{z^2}{x^2}+2\frac{z}{x}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$yy'+x = \dfrac{(x^2+y^2)^2}{2x^2}+\dfrac{x^2+y^2}{x}$$
$$2yy'+2x  +1= \dfrac{(x^2+y^2)^2}{x^2}+2\dfrac{x^2+y^2}{x}+1$$
$$(y^2+x^2+x)' =\left( \dfrac{y^2+x^2+x}{x}\right)^2$$
The DE is separable.
$$\dfrac {u'}{u^2} =\dfrac{1}{x^2}$$
Where $u=y^2+x^2+x$

Comment: Elegant. Will check it out soon

Comment: You're welcome @algevristis